# Raspberry Pi 2 and JavaFX8: Can't render small images without more GPU RAM

Tags: pi-2, java, javafx

I'm trying to write a simple FX8 image display program on the Raspberry Pi2 without increasing the GPU memory beyond the default 64MB.   I seem to get me a NullPointer Exception at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.drawTexture attempting to render the ImageView.  This is with the packaged Oracle JDK8 (build 1.8.0-b132).

The image is about as small as I can make it without sacrificing quality.  Is there anything I can do to reduce the amount of GPU memory required to render this simple image?

### MCVE:

My minimum demonstration is very straightforward: an AnchorView holding an ImageView, [displaying a 29kB PNG (1847x1080)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMoR.png).

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Image image = new Image("/Sponsor.png");
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(image);
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(imageview);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        imageview.setFitHeight(scene.getHeight());
        imageview.setFitWidth(scene.getWidth());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### Stack trace

```
glGetError 0x505
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.drawTexture(BaseGraphics.java:389)
    at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.drawTexture(BaseShaderGraphics.java:139)
    at com.sun.prism.image.Coords.draw(Coords.java:46)
    at com.sun.prism.image.CompoundCoords.draw(CompoundCoords.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGImageView.renderContent(NGImageView.java:134)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2043)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGImageView.doRender(NGImageView.java:103)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1951)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:225)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2043)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1951)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:469)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:324)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Maybe using javafx is the wrong way to go here?  Using shaders and textures implies it is engaging openGL, which is totally unnecessary to present png images.  I believe the minimum GPU mem for OGL use is 128 MB, which might explain your problem.  You should investigate this as a non pi specific javafx issue to confirm part of this.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point about it pulling in OGL.  I will investigate as a general javafx issue.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks.  [Crossposted to SO here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395037/can-i-display-an-image-with-javafx8-without-the-opengl-overhead)  Interesting suggestions, however, using the SW rendering pipeline fails with the current Oracle JDK.  The error message suggests making a bugreport at http://bugreport.sun.com/.  Is there a better way to get the news to Oracle?

Comment: @DSJustice: I think writing a Bug-Report there is the best way to let them know, because it is well managed and way better than "writing them an E-Mail" or so.