# How can I derive the Oracle build number from the Raspbian JDK package?

Tags: raspbian, java

I'm trying to report a [JDK bug](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37713/raspberry-pi-2-and-javafx8-cant-render-small-images-without-more-gpu-ram) to Oracle.   However, the Raspbian package number doesn't have the Oracle package number, and the `java -version` output doesn't match any of the expected build numbers.

Am I running 8u65, 8u66, early-access 8u72, or something else entirely?

```
    pi@pi ~ $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I think Raspbian started packaging the Oracle JDK which may be a source of confusion.  You might want to try installing [the latest version from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (it's the first one in that list, linux ARM v6/7 hard float, and the build number is in the package name, 8u65), confirm the bug with that, and then report.